# SQL query with MAX() and SUM() aggregates

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, max, ms-access-2010

After searching lots of other topics on here and other forums I cannot seem to find a solution to my problem.

What I'm trying to achieve is selecting the account with the highest "money spent" per shop.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
 SELECT MAX(s.Amount) MaxOfAmount
      , s.shopID
   FROM 
      ( SELECT SUM(OrderTotal) Amount
             , shopID
             , accountID 
          FROM Transactions 
         GROUP 
            BY shopID
             , accountID 
      ) s
  GROUP 
     BY s.shopID
```

This gives me the correct most money spent by an account per shopID, but I can't see the accountID that's associated with it. I tried adding selection.accountID to the first select. But then I have to add selection.accountID to the "GROUP BY" clause as well, which results in the same recordset as the "FROM" query.

I'm completely at a loss here, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this this should work.

```
 SELECT selection1.shopID,accountID,Amount
  FROM (SELECT SUM(OrderTotal) as Amount, shopID, accountID FROM Transactions GROUP BY     shopID, accountID )  AS selection1
  INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Max(selection2.Amount) AS MaxOfAmount, selection2.shopID
    FROM (SELECT SUM(OrderTotal) as Amount, shopID, accountID FROM Transactions GROUP BY shopID, accountID )  AS selection2
    GROUP BY selection2.shopID
)
MAX_AMOUNT ON
    MAX_AMOUNT.MaxOfAmount=selection1.Amount AND
    MAX_AMOUNT.shopID=selection1.shopID
```

Comment: That worked, thanks heaps!

I completely forgot I had to INNER JOIN the two SELECTS to get the result I wanted, makes sense now though!

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure, that you can do it in one query. Or this query will be some slow and not beautiful.

I solve same problems by creating "view" or "#tmp_table" with your subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(OrderTotal) as Amount, shopID, accountID INTO #shop_acc_amount FROM Transactions GROUP BY shopID, accountID

SELECT Max(selection.Amount) AS MaxOfAmount, selection.shopID,selection2.accountID
FROM #shop_acc_amount AS selection
JOIN #shop_acc_amount AS selection2 on selection2.shopID = selection.shopID AND selection2.Amount = Max(selection.Amount)
GROUP BY selection.shopID,selection2.accountID
```